# Protecting against PHP session DOS attacks

Tags: security, php, memcached

A popular move is to store PHP sessions in memcached. But it seems like this is wide open to an attack - someone could flood the server for new session requests and consume all your memory. What measures can be taken against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rate limiting?](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/)

[flood control?](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ)

[Cool down period?](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=12223293033)

[Don't know if stackoverflow has information that can help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026640/quick-and-easy-flood-protection)